# constructors inherited in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

[Excerpt from here:](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197893/why-are-constructors-not-inherited)

> Constructors are different from other class methods in that they create new objects, whereas other methods are invoked by existing objects. This is one reason constructors aren’t inherited. Inheritance means a derived object can use a base-class method, but, in the case of constructors, the object doesn’t exist until after the constructor has done its work.

1. Does a constructor create new object or when a object is called the
   constructor is called immediately?
2. It is said that a constructor and destructor is not inherited
   from the base class to the derived class but is the program below a
   contradiction, we are creating an object of the derived class but it
   outputs constructor and destructor of the base class also?

---

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        cout<< Const A called<<endl;
    }
    ~A(){
        cout<< Dest A called <<endl;
    }
};

Class B : public A{
public:
    B(){
        cout<< Const B called <<endl;
    }
    ~B(){
        cout<< Dest B called <<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    B obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Const A called
>
> Const B called
>
> Dest B called
>
> Dest A called

Comment: Define a constructor with a parameter in `A`, then see if `B` has inherited a constructor with a parameter.

Comment: That is a very misleading post, based on a very misleading quote from a book that isn't held in very high regard as a source of C++ knowledge. You should simply ignore all of it. Derived classes inherit all members from their base.

Comment: C++11 and later support constructor inheritance, so the **premise is incorrect**.

Answer (score 1):

A derived class `D` does not inherit a constructor from `B` in the sense that, specifying no explicit `D` constructors I can use my `B(int)` like to construct a `new D(1);`.

However, what I can do is use a base class constructor in the definition of a derived class constructor, like `D::D(void) : B(1) {}`.

Less abstract, suppose I have a constructor for `Person` that takes a `gender` parameter, I might wish to create a:

```
class Son: Person{
public:
    Son(void) : Person(male) {};
};
```

to construct a `Son`, which is obviously a `Person`, but certainly doesn't need parameterised `gender`.

Destructors are 'inherited' in the sense that on the closing brace of `D::~D(){}` a call to `~B()` is implied.